Why add a control via OpenLayer's getControls().extend?
I can change the z-index of a div so it appears above the map's viewport div.
Why add map controls via getControls().extend? What does that provide that I may not be accounting for?
Example:


const myControl = document.getElementById( "my-control");
const osm = new ol.source.OSM();

osm.setTileGridForProjection(
  "EPSG:4326",
  ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({ extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90] })
);

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: osm });

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [tileLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [-77.0231007567732604, 38.902979974562264],
    zoom: 3
  }),
  controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({ attribution: false, zoom: false }),
});

ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326").setExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85]);
#map {
  height: 128px;
  width: 256px;
}

.control {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(8,8,8,1) 80%, rgba(35,12,7,1) 80%, rgba(255,42,0,1) 90%, rgba(237,6,216,1) 90%);
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.5.2/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.5.2/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map">
  <div id="my-control" style="z-index: 1;" class="ol-unselectable ol-control control">
    <div > H </div>
  </div>
</div>



